# Does this bash script using grep look correct?

Tags: bash, shell, grep

I am having some strange rebooting issues and I think it is due to an error in my shell script.

```
#!/bin/bash

if ps -a | grep -q gridcoin
then
  echo nothing
else
  sudo reboot -h now
fi
```

The script is supposed to work like this:

Run the ps -a command so that all processes are listed. Pipe the results to grep and have grep check to see if any of the processes have the word "gridcoin" in them. If gridcoin is running, do nothing. If gridcoin is not one of the running processes, reboot the system.

I have a cron job that runs this script once every five minutes; however, my system keeps rebooting about every five minutes even when I know for a fact that gridcoin is running.

Please take a look at the code and see if it looks right before I start trying to herd other code cats.

Respectfully,

chadrick

Comment: Your syntax if fine, but be careful triggering reboots from a shell script. Why can't you just restart `gridcoin`? You can shorten your script negating the conditional with `if ! ps -a | grep -q gridcoin; then sudo reboot -h now; fi` to eliminate the `else` condition.

Comment: Hmm. Restarting gridcoin sure seems to make sense. I am not sure why I over-complicated things with doing a reboot. Thank you for the code review and abbreviated form. I will implement your suggestions right away and see what happens,

Answer (score 3):

I see at least two problems here. First, `ps -a` will not show processes that don't have a controlling terminal (so, basically, non-interactive processes); you want `ps -ax` to show *all* processes.

Second, depending on the timing, the `grep -q gridcoin` command may be listed as a running process, and of course it finds itself, meaning that it mistakes itself for the gridcoin process. If you have the `pgrep` program available, replace both `ps` and `grep` with it, since it automatically avoids listing itself. Unfortunately, it doesn't have a `-q` option like `grep`, so you have to redirect its output to /dev/null:

```
if pgrep gridcoin >/dev/null
```

If `pgrep` is not available, there are two standardish idioms to prevent `grep` from finding itself:

```
if ps -ax | grep -q '[g]ridcoin'    # Adding brackets prevents it from matching itself

if ps -ax | grep gridcoin | grep -vq grep    # Remove grep processes from consideration
```

Also, as David C. Rankin pointed out, rebooting the entire system to restart one process is overkill; just restart that one process.